# calculate the Probability: What is the probability that no one makes the right decision?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, probability, stochastic

I'm trying to solve an exercise from the stochastic project. Is anybody already done such exercises?

Consider a jury trial in which it takes 9 of the 12 jurors to convict the defendant; that is, in order for the defendant to be convicted, at least 8 of the jurors must vote him guilty. If we assume that jurors act independently and that, whether or not the defendant is guilty, each makes the right decision with probability θ (here could be 0.75 or 0.80), what is the probability that the jury renders a correct decision?
the questions are:
**1) How many jurors making the right decision can be expected? 2) What is the probability that no one makes the right decision?**

Thanks!
BR
Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How many jurors making the right decision can be expected?
   It's `12*θ`
2. What is the probability that no one makes the right decision?
   It's `(1-θ)^12`